# Chromium half window

Tags: xorg, chromium

Chromium launches via:
@chromium --kioski localhost:8080
but screen is always half. Can't resize, can't do anything, not even without the kioski option

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

right click in the top app top bar, choose uncheck use chrome theme (or something like this). Resize to fit to screen, done.
Now kiosk mode will work fine on full screen.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I running @chromium in same format: `@chromium` with kiosk mode and other parameters. Has the same problem.

To resolve it I run `startx` (to run GUI desctop) and maximized it there. Than `sudo reboot` did the job.